# NEW APP - Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: android, keystore

I want to generate a signed APK for a new app (in Google Play Console is still as "draft") but, when I try insert the passowrd of a keystore **just created**, Android Studio give me this error:

"Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

And it's impossible, because I created a new keystore in that moment.

(I tried to set the same password for keystore and alias, with no luck)

What should I do?

EDIT: Checking for the error, i saw this line "Failed to read key key0 from store" (it was about the debug.keystore).
I tried to delete that key and build again in order to get another debug.keystore, but the same error appears.

Comment: if its only draft, just delete everything and start again, you may have accidentally typo'd the PW

Comment: I made the draft after Android Studio gave me the error